# How to override /vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/system.php

Tags: magento2, overrides, log

I want to override this file

> vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/System.php

Basically I want to disable **system.log** and **exception.log** from **var/log** folder. I found that

> vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/System.php

this file can write in log.

Does anyone know how to override this file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this file

> vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Handler/System.php

here in this directory..

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Logger/Handler/System.php

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Its working for me. +1 for this.

Comment: Thanks, Buddy for appreciation! :)