# Magento 2 Override public static method of framework class

Tags: magento2, di, coding-standards, preference

I want to override `public static function getCorrectFileName` method of `Magento\Framework\File\Uploader`, I have check with Preference and Plugin but it is not working for me.

Anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: you cannot override static functions.

Comment: We can not override with Preference ?

Comment: We can't override using preference. Try with other method

Comment: I hope this answer will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293100/how-to-override-vendor-magento-framework-logger-handler-system-php/293101#293101

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting a static method is impossible, because the interpreter call them using a class name directly, so no one preference could get around this logic. It is a PHP restriction, not Magento. You can create a similar module\class and use it instead of the base Magento module\class.

Comment: Yes right @Siarhey Uchukhlebau, I have do another way and it working fine.

Comment: @NiranjanGondaliya Can you let me know how did you achieve it? I need to increase filename length condition to 128 instead of 90 in that static function.

Comment: @NiranjanGondaliya How did you go about extending or overwriting this method?